# Debugging emails

Tags: magento-2.1, email, debugging

I have a Magento ver. 2.1.3 setup that is not sending any emails.

I'm trying to fix this, but nothing I do seems to work.

My server has protections against spam which forces scripts to use SMTP.

I've read that I would need an extension for that, so I've tried `MagePal_GmailSmtpApp` and `Mageplaza_Smtp`, none of them worked.

I've followed their instructions correctly and they were installed correctly, I could setup their config in the dashboard, both of them offered a "**test**" email and they both worked, it's just the regular Magento emails that were not working.

The `gmailsmtpapp` extension at least gave an error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Smartwave\Porto\Model\Transport\Interceptor::getMessage() in /home/user/public_html/vendor/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp/Plugin/Mail/TransportPlugin.php:29 

Stack trace:
#0 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): MagePal\GmailSmtpApp\Plugin\Mail\TransportPlugin->aroundSendMessage(Object(Smartwave\Porto\Model\Transport\Interceptor), Object(Closure))
#1 /home/user/public_html/var/generation/Smartwave/Porto/Model/Transport/Interceptor.php(26): Smartwave\Porto\Model\Transport\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendMessage', Array, Array)
#2 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/EmailNotification.php(239): Smartwave\Porto\Model\Transport\Interceptor->sendMessage()
#3 /home/user/public_html/vendor/magento/module-customer/Model/EmailNotification.php(297): Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification->sendEmailTemplate(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Customer), 'customer/passw in /home/user/public_html/vendor/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp/Plugin/Mail/TransportPlugin.php on line 29
```

I've tracked down the Interceptor class to a file in `/var/generation/Smartwave/Porto/Model/Transport`

It looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Smartwave\Porto\Model\Transport;

/**
 * Interceptor class for @see \Smartwave\Porto\Model\Transport
 */
class Interceptor extends \Smartwave\Porto\Model\Transport implements \Magento\Framework\Interception\InterceptorInterface
{
    use \Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Mail\MessageInterface $message)
    {
        $this->___init();
        parent::__construct($message);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function sendMessage()
    {
        $pluginInfo = $this->pluginList->getNext($this->subjectType, 'sendMessage');
        if (!$pluginInfo) {
            return parent::sendMessage();
        } else {
            return $this->___callPlugins('sendMessage', func_get_args(), $pluginInfo);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to go more in depth to debug this, but I can't find any useful information or documentation that is for programmers.

On some answers here I've read that Magento is queuing emails and a cron-job is sending them, where is it queuing them? Could I just make a script that reads this queue and process the emails myself?

Anyone knows where I could find more information on how the email system works in Magento 2.1?

Comment: have you tried cron run? it will execute queue emails and also try contact page dummy entry submit once. if everything is configured properly on server then it give success message after form submit.

Comment: I'm no longer working on this, sorry, but thanks for the comment

Comment: Looks like probably the `Smartwave_Porto` extension has created a plugin/interceptor on `\Magento\Email\Model\Transport::sendMessage`, maybe for a theming related reason, hard to know without being able to review the extension’s customizations.